# Order of error messages to reflect the order of input fields in Jquery validation

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I've slightly modified positioning of error messages in Jquery Validation. As you can see, the error messages are displayed below the  tag for a group of input fields. However, with this approach, I've introduced an issue where the order of the error messages are not in the same order as the input elements. In this example, I want the error message for the month to appear first then the year but the order is reversed.

However, If I change `insertAfter` to `insertBefore`the order is corrected but obviously the error messages is then inserted above the  tag (although visually this is not the case and not sure why).

My question is if there's an easier way to reorder the error messages so that they are displayed in the same order as the inputs.
Thanks in advance.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.form').validate({
    errorElement: "span",
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
      var parent = element.closest('.form-group');
      var target = parent.find('legend');
      error.insertAfter(target);
    }
  });

  $.validator.addClassRules({
    "month-validation": {
      required: true
    },
    "year-validation": {
      required: true
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.error {
  display: block;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-8">
        <form action="index.php" class="form">
          <div class="form-group">
            <fieldset>
              <legend>Enter month and year</legend>
              <div class="form-row align-items-center">
                <div class="col">
                  <label class="form-hint" for="month">Month</label>
                  <input type="text" name="month" class="form-control month-validation" id="month" data-msg-required="Enter the month" />
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                  <label class="form-hint" for="year">Year</label>
                  <input type="text" name="year" class="form-control year-validation" id="year" data-msg-required="Enter the year" />
                </div>
              </div>
            </fieldset>
          </div>
          <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.2/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can change your target from `legend` to `.form-row` so you can use `insertBefore`

```js
$(function() {
  $('.form').validate({
    errorElement: "span",
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
      var parent = element.closest('.form-group');
      var target = parent.find('.form-row');
      error.insertBefore(target);
    }
  });

  $.validator.addClassRules({
    "month-validation": {
      required: true
    },
    "year-validation": {
      required: true
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.error {
  display: block;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-8">
        <form action="index.php" class="form">
          <div class="form-group">
            <fieldset>
              <legend>Enter month and year</legend>
              <div id='errors'></div>
              <div class="form-row align-items-center">
                <div class="col">
                  <label class="form-hint" for="month">Month</label>
                  <input type="text" name="month" class="form-control month-validation" id="month" data-msg-required="Enter the month" />
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                  <label class="form-hint" for="year">Year</label>
                  <input type="text" name="year" class="form-control year-validation" id="year" data-msg-required="Enter the year" />
                </div>
              </div>
            </fieldset>
          </div>
          <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.2/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```